# Can this CSS syntax be improved, be made more organized?

Tags: css, refactoring

Is there a cleaner way to write the same css **given that `input name f1 to f7` are all `type=text` like the first line?**

Thanks

```
#tform input[type="text"]  { -moz-border-radius:6px; border: 1px solid green; }

#tform input[name="f1"],
#tform input[name="f2"],
#tform input[name="f3"], 
#tform input[name="f4"],
#tform input[name="f5"] { width:40%; }

#tform input[name="f6"] { width:80%; display:block; }

#tform input[name="f7"] { width:80%; }
```

My problem is actually that I have 3 additional inputs: `name f8, f8, f10`, also `type=text` which I'm letting them set width naturally without `width:%;`.

I thought about putting the 40% into the first line and letting the rest override it, but then those additional 3 will take the 40% by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear it up and make use of class selectors:

```
.input_text{ -moz-border-radius:6px; border: 1px solid green; }
.stylea{ width:40%; }
.styleb{ width:80%; display:block; }
.stylec{ width:80%;}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="f1" class="input_text stylea" />
<input type="text" name="f2" class="input_text stylea" />
<input type="text" name="f3" class="input_text stylea" />
<input type="text" name="f4" class="input_text stylea" />
<input type="text" name="f5" class="input_text stylea" />
<input type="text" name="f6" class="input_text styleb" />
<input type="text" name="f7" class="input_text stylec" />
```

For any additional input elements, you can just use the base CSS selector style, in this case `.input_text`, and not apply the additional class selectors (`.stylea, .styleb, .stylec`) used by others.

So when you add the rest:

```
<input type="text" name="f8" class="input_text" />
<input type="text" name="f9" class="input_text" />
<input type="text" name="f10" class="input_text" />
```

They'll keep the same look as the other inputs but not be constrained with the rest of the width sizing.

Comment: Do you have to make use of attribute selectors?

Comment: `stylea` and all that are just placeholders for better class definitions.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Considered giving f1-f5 a class instead? It might be a few extra bytes of HTML, but you get far cleaner CSS.

```
.yourClass { width: 40%; }
```

Comment: have to agree with this. it's a good solution. Also probably makes sense to give f6 and f7 classes that represent their semantic meaning/purpose